# Регистрация и авторизация в Laravel 5.5 не работает

Tags: php, laravel, регистрация

```
Использовал авторизацию 'из коробки',т.е. набрав php artisan make:Auth, но решил создать новую view для регистрации
Регистрация через стандартную view из коробки работает, а через view, которую создал я - редиректит меня на тот же адрес, где находится моя форма для регистрации
```

main/blade.php - новое представление для регистрации

{{ csrf_field() }}

                    
                        Name
                        

                    
                    
                        Password
                        

                    
                    
                        Repeat
                        

                    
                    
                        Email
                        

                    

                Join

web.php
Auth::routes(); // из коробки

Контроллер, к которому идет обращение

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{


    use RegistersUsers;


    protected $redirectTo = '/home';


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }


    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',

        ]);
    }


    protected function create(array $data){



            return User::create([
                'name' => $data['name'],
                'byear' => $data['byear'],
                'bmonth' => $data['bmonth'],
                'bday' => $data['bday'],
                'sex' => $data['sex'],
                'email' => $data['email'],
                'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
                'avatar' => 'avatardefault.jpg',
            ]);

        // }

    }
```

Comment: <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">{{ csrf_field() }}<input type='text' value="{{ old('name') }}" ><input type='password' v-model='password' name="password"><input type='password' v-model='passwordRep' name=''><input type='text' name='email' value="{{ old('email') }}" v-model='birthDay'><button class='btnNext' type="submit">Join</button>
</form>

Comment: Это созданный мной view

Answer (score 0):

Во первых ты можешь изменять view(представление), которое ты получил из под коробки - это находиться: ***resource -> views -> auth -> login.blade.php && register.blade.php***

во вторых ты можешь создать свой ***route*** в ***web.php*** для регистрации, входа и т.д и там же указывать свои представления